# Rails: How can I start a PORO/job/worker right after deploy of the Docker container?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, jobs, rails-activejob

My story:
I need to develop a small app which consumes a Twitter stream.

What is the best way to start my PORO `streamer.rb` right after the container being deployed?
Just a simple background process which called only once on the app start.

UPD: I am searching for a solution like it was made by Capistrano years ago:

```rb
after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:some_task_name'
```

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: "In a second container" is the standard answer; there are several [sample applications](https://docs.docker.com/samples/) in the Docker documentation and almost all of these involve multiple containers in some form.